# CS0012 error when trying to deploy Origami (Hololens 101 tutorial) to Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

This is my first time using Hololens so I did everything from begining. I followed the online Holograms 101 tutorial.

Since I have a physical hololens, so I only followed the section "Installation checklist for HoloLens". I first installed a Unity 2017.4.2f2, then I installed a Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.7, community) with "UWP development" and "game development with Unity" selected.

Then I just followed the instructions in Chapter 1. Everything went well. In "Building Settings", I selected "Universal Windows Platform", "target device" is hololens, "Build type" is D3D, "SDK" is Latest installed since there is no option "Universal 10", "visual studio version" is Latest installed, "Build and Run on" is local machine, and I checked "Unity C# projects".

After opening the sln in visual studio, I set "release" "x86" "device"(my hololens is connected via usb) and then "start without debugging", and then I got the following 2 errors:

[image]

I have tried searching online for solution and I did see some people with the similar issue, but most of them are using an emulator instead of a real hololens. I have tried some solutions independent of emulator/hololens, but they didn't solve my problems.

Now I really don't know how to deal with it. I think the problem is from my visual studio because I also tried with my Unity 5.6 and it gave me the same errors. Another thing when installing the tools is that I just downloaded those listed under "Mixed Reality Toolkit", should I also build those solutions?

FYI, here are the settings of my visual studio:

[image]

And here is the player setting of my unity 2017.4.2:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? I really need to make it work by next week and now I'm very upset :(

Thank you very much in advance for any help!!!

Comment: After you chose “Universal Windows Platform” in the build settings, did you click on the “Switch Platform” button and see the Unity logo move next to it? That step is necessary for the choice to take effect

Comment: @Leon Yes, I do click the button and switch the platform first...

Comment: What options do you have in the SDK dropdown if you open it? (Where you see “Latest Installed”)

Comment: I have 10.0.10240.0, 10.0.10586.0, 10.0.14393.0, 10.0.15063.0, 10.0.16299.0, 10.0.17134.0. Is there any confliction?

Comment: I don’t think so. It was just to check that you did in fact have the version 10 SDK installed (which you do), since you were expecting to see Universal 10 but didn’t.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using the Mixed Reality Toolkit, you can setup your project, scene and capabilities from the `Mixed Reality Toolkit` menu in Unity Editor and next Configure. You can take a pick of some similar menu [here](https://github.com/sGambolati/HoloWorkShop/blob/master/exercise1.md#task-3-configure-your-project-to-work-with-hololens).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but it turned out to be more `assembly that is not referenced` errors. Does it matter that I use VS2017 and Unity 2017.4 instead of VS2015 and Unity 2017.2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, let me answer my own question. I have figured it out.

If you also use win10, VS2017, and unity 2017 (I switched to 2017.2, but I guess this should also work for 2017.3/4), then in the case of these two annoying "assembly that is not referenced" problem, check whether you have a reference called "windows" under Origami assembly->References. If it is not there, then right click References, on the left side you will see a "Browse", under the Browse, browse to add the reference which is supposed to be at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Facade\windows.winmd

I hope this helps you guys. Good luck!